# Best way to find roots of a multidimensional, scalar function with SciPy

Tags: python, scipy

Suppose I have a function whose range is a scalar but whose domain is a vector. For example:

```
def func(x):
  return x[0] + 1 + x[1]**2
```

What's a good way to find <s>the</s> *a* root of this function? `scipy.optimize.fsolve` and `scipy.optimize.root` expect `func` to return a vector (rather than a scalar), and `scipy.optimize.newton` only takes scalar arguments. I can redefine `func` as

```
def func(x):
  return [x[0] + 1 + x[1]**2, 0]
```

Then `root` and `fsolve` can find a root, but the zeros in the Jacobian means it won't always do a good job. For example:

```
fsolve(func, array([0,2]))
=> array([-5,  2])
```

It'll only vary the first parameter but not the second, meaning that it often finds a zero that's far away.

---

EDIT: it looks like the following redefinition of func works better:

```
def func(x):
  fx = x[0] + 1 + x[1]**2
  return [fx, fx]

fsolve(func, array([0,5]))
=>array([-16.27342781,   3.90812331])
```

So it's now willing to change both parameters. The code is still kind of ugly though.

Comment: Any point of the form (-1 - y**2, y) is a root, so it doesn't make sense to ask for *the* root.  In the generic case, you should expect the set of solutions to `f(x,y)=0` to be a curve in the `(x,y)` plane.  You need a second function or a constraint if you want a unique solution.

Comment: Yes, if you want to be pedantic, I'm looking for "a root" -- preferably one relatively close to the initial guess. I.e. I'm looking for something that behaves like `scipy.optimize.fsolve` or `scipy.optimize.root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since -- for my problem -- I have a good initial guess and a non-crazy function, Newton's method works well. For a scalar, multidimensional function, Newton's method becomes:

[image: equation]

Here's a rough code example:

```
def func(x): #the function to find a root of
  return x[0] + 1 + x[1]**2

def dfunc(x): #the gradient of that function
  return array([1, 2*x[1]])

def newtRoot(x0, func, dfunc):
  x = array(x0)
  for n in xrange(100): # do at most 100 iterations
    f  = func(x)
    df = dfunc(x)

    if abs(f) < 1e-6: # exit function if we're close enough
      break

    x = x - df*f/norm(df)**2 # update guess
  return x
```

In use:

```
nsolve([0,2],func,dfunc)
=> array([-1.0052546 ,  0.07248865])

func([-1.0052546 ,  0.07248865])
=> 4.3788225025098715e-09
```

Not bad! Of course, this function is very rough, but you get the idea. It also won't work well for "tricky" functions or where you don't have a good starting guess. I think I'll use something like this but then fall back to `fsolve` or `root` if Newton's method doesn't converge.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the minimization of the absolute value of your function using `fmin`?
For example:

```
>>> import scipy.optimize as op
>>> import numpy as np

>>> def func(x):
>>>     return x[0] + 1 + x[1]**2
>>> func1 = lambda x: np.abs(func(x))

>>> tmp = op.fmin(func1, [10000., 10000.])
>>> func(tmp)
0.0
>>> print tmp
[-8346.12025122    91.35162971]
```

Comment: I wouldn't personally use this solution, except for some kinds of functions, because the choice of the starting point is important and the Jacobi is not continue.
If you know the shape of your function and it is not very complicated, this can be a solution.

Comment: I thought about trying to minimize the absolute value (or square), but I figured it might be more accurate (and possibly faster) to look for roots rather than minimize the function. For the actual problem I'm trying to solve, I have a pretty good initial guess, and the function is nice and smooth, so I really only need Newton (or secant) method.